# Thymeleaf (Java Spring): Cannot get mvc.uri to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have recently started to develop with Spring.io and Spring Boot and have integrated Thymeleaf into my web app. I am now tring to implement reverse routing using [mvc.uri](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html) but I cannot seem to make it work.

This is the web controller (`HomeController`) displaying the view where I am trying to reverse route:

```
package com.twlab.billigalan.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView home() {
        //String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName("HousingLoansController#main").build();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        //model.addObject("url",url);
        model.setViewName("pages/main/home");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/server-error")
    public String error(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("errorCode", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code"));
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        String errorMessage = null;
        if (throwable != null) {
          errorMessage = throwable.getMessage();
        }
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        return "pages/main/error.html";
    }
}
```

This is the view:

```
<html
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
layout:decorator="layouts/master.layout">
<head>
    <title>Billiga lån</title>
</head>
<body class="home">
    <div class="panel-body" layout:fragment="content">
        <a th:href="#{mvc.uri('HomeController#home').build()}">Test</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the master layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootswatch-sandstone/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    th:href="@{/webjars/bootswatch-sandstone/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
    rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/favicon.ico" th:href="@{/favicon.ico}" />
    <title>Billiga lån</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div id="header" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/" id="logo">Billiga lån</a>
            <span id="tagline">Billigaste lånen hittar du här!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Visa meny</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand frontpage"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Låna pengar snabbt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a th:href="#{mvc.uri('HousingLoansController#main').build()}">Bolån</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Bil-lån</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-2 panel panel-default" layout:fragment="sidebar">
            <div class="panel-heading">Snabbstart</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <aside id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
                    <div class="menu-sidomeny-container">
                        <ul id="menu-sidomeny" class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Låna pengar snabbt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lån med betalningsanmärkning</a></li>
                            <li><a th:uri="mvcUrl('HousingLoansController#main')">Bolån</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bil-lån</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body" layout:fragment="content">

                </div>
                <!-- /panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /panel -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#content -->
        <div id="right-sidebar" class="col-md-2 panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body" layout:fragment="right-sidebar">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#main -->
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<div id="pre-footer">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- /pre-footer -->
<div id="footer"></div>
<!-- /footer -->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"
        th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootswatch-sandstone/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        th:src="@{/webjars/bootswatch-sandstone/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the controller referenced from the layout (`HousingLoansController`):

```
package com.twlab.billigalan.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HousingLoansController {

    @RequestMapping("/bolan")
    public ModelAndView main() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("quickstart",null);
        model.setViewName("pages/housing-loans/housing-loans");
        return model;
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

> 2015-12-16 12:33:55.099  INFO 8072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2015-12-16 12:33:55.099  INFO
>   8072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
>   2015-12-16 12:33:55.116  INFO 8072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet
>   'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 17 ms 2015-12-16
>   12:33:55.639 ERROR 8072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             :
>   [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template
>   "pages/main/home": Could not parse as expression:
>   "#{mvc.uri('HousingLoansController#main').build()}"
>   (layouts/master.layout:42) 2015-12-16 12:33:55.644 ERROR 8072 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse
>   as expression: "#{mvc.uri('HousingLoansController#main').build()}"
>   (layouts/master.layout:42)] with root cause
>
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse
>   as expression: "#{mvc.uri('HousingLoansController#main').build()}"
>   (layouts/master.layout:42)    at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:238)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:79)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:40)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:65)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringHrefAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(SpringHrefAttrProcessor.java:68)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedAttributeValues(AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:62)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_65]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [the example here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#building-uris-to-controllers). `#mvc` is an expression object, so must be accessed from within a thymeleaf expression, eg:

```
<a th:href="${#mvc.url('HomeController#home').build()}">Test</a>
```

Note that `#mvc` is contained and referenced from within the `${...}` notation.

Comment: Thank you!

Now I get the following error message:
Method call: Method uri(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.Mvc type

I am running the latest version of spring boot which loads: spring core 4.2.3.RELEASE, thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE and thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.

Comment: @ErikT `#mvc.uri` doesn't seem to exist (though the Thymeleaf docs seem to suggest it should). Perhaps `#mvc.url` will do what you need instead? Note that you have to use the initials for your controller, ie. `#mvc.url('HC#home')`

Comment: You're absolutely right. They have changed the method to url, and now it works. Big Thanks!